# MySQL Item attribute depending on category

Tags: mysql, attributes, categories

Lets say I have a store which sells general products... for example clothes and computers.
An item can have only one category.

So I have items which have a category (clothes, computers, etc), and depending on the category the item has attributes, and those attributes have values also depending on the category.

What would be a good approach to this? 
So far I have a tbl_item which has a many-many relation to a table tbl_attribute, but I'm guessing I should change it to tbl_category maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you'd have:

```
item(item_id, name, category_id)
item_attributes(item_id, attribute_id)
attributes(attribute_id, category_id, name)
```

So, for a given item, you lookup the category_id.  Take that to get a list of available attributes, and insert the appropriate ones into the item_attributes table.

Comment: what about the value of the attribute? for example if category is clothes then the item_attribute should be size and the values for that attribute should be S, M, L, XL, etc... but if its a PC then the attribute should be lets say CPU and the values sometihng like i3, i5, i7, etc

Comment: That sounds like additional information that you would indeed want to store.  What would you propose?

Comment: Dunno, maybe another table attribute_value ? Values will be ofc predefined

Comment: How about attribute_group(attribute_group_id, name) for things like "Size" and then change to attributes(attribute_id, attribute_group_id, name, sort_order) for ("S", "M", "L")?